# What is the market impact of OTC trading ETFs?

Tags: etf, market-impact

I read an interesting statement [here](http://advisor.morningstar.com/products/conference/brochure/ETF%20Total%20Cost%20Analysis.pdf):

> "If an ETF’s market price tracks its NAV well, it is likely to have a
> small market impact. On the other hand, if the market price is more
> volatile than the fund’s NAV, a large order could move the price
> before a market maker would be willing to step in and close that gap,
> leading to higher market impact costs."

Now, I am aware of the standard heuristic "$\beta$-exponent participation rate" market impact model as discussed by Almgren [here](http://www.courant.nyu.edu/%7Ealmgren/papers/eqf.pdf) and in this [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43/is-there-a-standard-model-for-market-impact).

With ETFs and OTC trading, the situation seems to be quite different depending on what your counterparty does. They can

- Keep the position open
- Buy/Sell the position at the exchange
- Match it with a trade of different direction (in-house)
- Hedge
- Trigger the Creation/Redemption process

Now some of these actions would directly impact the price while the others won't.
The question is: Is there a way or a model to quantify market impact effects in this case?

I will be glad to accept specific models or empirical studies about this as an answer. Please do not hesitate to post your practical experience/findings (as a trader/market maker) in this topic as an answer as well!